# Switching between frames

Tags: java, jframe

I am creating a program that has a switch user feature, so basically I have two frames, log in frame and the main frame. The problem is, after I log in using the switch user feature the second time, my main frame gets so messy.

[image]

[image]

Here's my code for log in frame

```
if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Log In")){
        try {
            rs.absolute(0);
            while(rs.next()){
                if(rs.getString("Username").equals(login.usert.getText()) && rs.getString("Password").equals(login.passt.getText())){
                    rs = st.executeQuery("select * from employee where Email ='"+login.usert.getText()+"'");
                    while(rs.next()){
                        if(rs.getString("Email").equals(login.usert.getText())){
                            eid = rs.getInt("EID");
                            new gui().user.setText("User" + rs.getString("Nickname"));
                            login.frame.dispose();
                            break;
                        }   
                    }
                }
                else{

                    login.error.setText("Invalid username/password");
                }

            }

        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here's my code for switch user button

```
ubutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            mainFrame.dispose();
            login.frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice) and [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for a possible solution

Comment: It's difficult to be sure, but given all the "transparency" you could have a painting issue related to; not calling `super.paintX` when overriding paint methods; using alpha based colors for the background instead of `setOpaque`; some other thing which isn't diagnosable from the out of context code snippet you've provided

Comment: Does your program start with the login or the main frame? Where is the code that actually creates the main frame? What is the gui class and how does `new gui().user.setText("User" + rs.getString("Nickname"));` do anything that has a lasting effect or is even shown to the user?

Comment: all panels are set to setOpaque(false), new gui is a class that holds the main frame. my program starts with the log in frame..sorry I am having triuble editing my post so I just answered your questions here... Ill also read the link you've provided. As always, thank you